# Can't retrieve fully-qualified assembly name using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName()

Tags: c#, .net

I am attempting to extract an embedded resource from the currently executing assembly in C#.

My fully-qualified assembly name is of the form **`Alpha.Beta.Gamma.Delta.MyTaskLibrary`** (obviously, this isn't *actually* the name; but the number of parts exactly corresponds to the name I have. The default namespace of the project is `Alpha.Beta.Gamma.Delta.MyTaskLibrary`.

When I execute `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name`, instead of showing me the above name, it shows me **`Gamma.Delta.MyTaskLibrary`**.

On the other hand, when I do `typeof(ClassName).AssemblyQualifiedName`, I get the fully-qualified name as above along with the version, culture and public key token.

Why is there this difference in behavior?

**EDIT**: My ultimate goal is to get an embedded resource from within this assembly by using

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(assemblyName + "." + fileName)
```

It's precisely this `assemblyName` that I'm trying to retrieve. I tried this method call with both `"Alpha.Beta.Gamma.Delta.MyTaskLibrary.ResourceFile.ext"` and `"Gamma.Delta.MyTaskLibrary.ResourceFile.ext"`, and only the former worked.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name` gives you a name of the assembly. Usually it is the name of the file where assembly is located.

In other words, you could have assembly named `Abcde.dll` and have namespace `My.Namespace.Name.Inside.Of.Abcde.Assembly`. They are not related. And project's default namespace is... hm, it is a default. It doesn't get compiled into resulting assembly. It is just a Hint for Visual Studio which namespace it should place a class/interface/whatever to if you adding new item to this concrete project.

How are you going to get name of the class that is not even mentioned in your request?

Answer (score 0):

You get call [GetModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d3c18c2.aspx)() on the assembly and iterate over the collection of modules and access the [FullyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.fullyqualifiedname.aspx) property on each module.